# design pattern to use in which GUI is automatically updating using database and business logic is indepenent to GUI?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, design-patterns

I am working for an project in which i need to listen from the several clients very often, do some processing on that and save the processed data into the database. I used producer and consumer approach for it. This can only insert or update.

And then user open separate application which is GUI (Swing base)to see this data mostly though JTable. Whenever any new entries made to the database then it should be visible on GUI as well automatically. Through GUI user can allow to update or delete the data.

My doubt is which design pattern should i use for it. What i thought to use singleton in the first case as only 1 connection is allowed and insertion is allowed one after another.

for GUI i am not able to figure out what to use.

Initially i thought to use MVC but i thought it would make my code more complex as my viewer and controller(1st part) is not related. person who login from GUI is not contact or linked with the 1st part. It needs to link directly from the database.

Comment: MVC for your Swing application is fine (M as the model of your Swing components), but your Swing model (Java POJO) has to be populated from your database to maintain synchronization with the other clients.

Comment: but how to manage between model and view as view is different application and controller loads the data into the database using model only. I am sorry i have very limited idea and this is my first project and i worked on small projects before only

Comment: but Smutje, as per my knowledge model and view doesnot communicate each other..